# Socket.io authenticating as a client

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I made a nodeJS script to automate a few actions on a website - which is **not** mine!

To have a bit more control over what is going on, I would like to listen to the events on the website's socket.io stream.

**Works in NODE so far**:

- Logging into the website and receiving their cookies as a string for further requests
- Sending requests with the cookies from the login (do the actual actions)
- Open a websocket connection and listen to the public (!) events

**Doesn't work in NODE yet**:

- Read "private" events that are only being sent to a specific user (me)

I inspected a XHR request that is happening in chrome when clicking a specific button on this website. After this request has been sent, the websocket connection on chrome emits events about the status of my action. Of course, these events are only being sent to the user who performed this action.

Doing the exact same request in node (with the cookies from the website login) gives the right response (success), but the socket stream i opened before, only shows some public events - nothing about my actions.

As seen here, it logs in, displays the website's cookies, opens a socket stream. Then it sends a XHR POST request with the displayed cookies in the headers. The response says "success", but the socket.io events popping up once a second are only the public ones (userCount).

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwE5G.jpg

After sending the request, there should be events like "step_calc" popping up, displaying the status of my action.

## My script

After receiving the website's login cookies as a string, I am running this:

```
const io = require('socket.io-client');
const request = require('request');

main()

function main() {

            var socket = io(socketURL, {});

            socket.on('connect', function () {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    performAction();                                // Send XHR to server
                    console.log(" > Sending XHR request...")
                }, 1500)
            });

            socket.on('step_calc', function (data) {               // Personal event about my action
                console.log(" >>> Event = step_calc: " + data)
            });

            socket.on('login_time', function (data) {               // Personal event being displayed every few seconds IF LOGGED IN (chrome)                    console.log(" >>> Event = step_calc: " + data)
            });

            socket.on('userCount', function (data) {                // Public event
                console.log(" >>> Event = userCount: " + data)
            });

            socket.on('disconnect', function () {
                console.log(" > [Disconnected]");
            });
}
```

1500ms after being connected to the socket, it would send the XHR request that should make the server emit information to the socket - performAction().

When I check the chrome console:

- **step_calc** follows to a successfull XHR request (account specific)
- **login_time** is being displayed every 2 seconds, but only if i am logged in (account specific)
- **userCount** is being displayed all the time - to everybody

I checked the socket.io-client's API guide and found out about socketIDs. But it only says, how to **get** this id after connecting to the server...

> https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md#socket

... and yes ... when opening the website, the first thing chrome does, is send a GET request to the website, with data like this:

> EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1493058868222-0

The response contains some kind of "sid".

> {"sid":"g_mqoOS__________bHb","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}

### Well...

- Now that I have gathered all of this information, how can I use it?
- How can I make the socket connection be "connected" to the cookies that I got from the login (which I am using to send requests to the website)?

I really hope that my question is kind of understandable. Any help is appreciated, I have already put a lot of time into trying to make it work by myself.

Thanks a lot!

## Edit:

I tried to add the same cookies from the handshake in chrome. One weird thing is, that the first XHR it does when i open the website (which seems to be the handshake), already contains a cookie named "io", which is then replaced by a new one. If I check the chrome console>application>cookies, I can't see this cookie at all. Where does it come from?

Left side: The request under the XHR tab on chrome
Right side: This is being displayed under the Websocket tab

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4hWh.jpg

- Are those two different requests or is it the same one in some way?
- Does this information help somehow help to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're not passing the session cookies to the `socket.io-client` constructor, which would probably mean that the socket connection isn't being authenticated.

Try this:

```
var socket = io(socketURL, {
  extraHeaders: {
    Cookie : '...'
  }
});
```

Documented [here](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io-client#nodejs-with-extraheaders).

Comment: Thanks, I just tried to pass the cookies from the website login this way. It doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't show any account specific information on the socket. I just saw, that the request when opening the website seems to "refresh" an "io" cookie while returning a new sid. I am really sorry, never worked with socket.io and I am confused about which cookies i would need to send. This is what's going on with the cookies during this "io" request: http://i.imgur.com/wzPpAx6.jpg

Comment: I guess you should send any cookies that the server is sending back. I'm not sure how much `socket.io-client` will do by itself in terms of sending back specific cookies, though.

Comment: Probably not too much, since the cookies I get from logging into the website don't include this "io" cookie for example. Chrome must be doing something in the background. Any idea, if it's possible for me as a client to change the Sid? Maybe I have to recreate the request that responds with an SID and do something like socked. id = response.Sid?

Comment: The socket id is something that the server creates, I doubt that the client can change it. As for cookies, you need to look specifically for the cookies being sent and received during the `socket.io` handshake protocol (which is initially done over HTTP to `/socket.io/...`).

Comment: Ahhh. So the cookies in the extra headers you linked me are used for the handshake I can see in chrome? So if I manage to send the same set of cookies, this could work. Will try and report. Thank you!

Comment: It seems like I can't recreate this same set of cookies. I added something to the end of my original post. Would be nice if you could take a look at it!

Comment: How the `socket.io` handshake works is that it will first use plain HTTP(S) requests, and then upgrade to Websockets is they are available. The initial XHR request contains an `io` cookie that may be stale, so the server responds by sending back a new one. I _think_ that this cookie doesn't need to be set, but the other ones (`__cfduid`, `_ym_uid`, etc) probably should.

Comment: Tried, same result. Is it right to add the cookies as a string like "__cfduid=1234653; _ym_uid=jdshfu23823; ..." or should this be an array? (Tried both without success actually)

Comment: I think it's okay to pass them as string, AFAIK it's the "raw" cookie header that you set.